# image src transitions appears for the user

Tags: javascript, html, css, eclipse, cordova

I was doing a simple design for a mobile phonegap application and i just wanted to change the src of an image in a div according to a certain click event but this src is in another div and when the src changes according to the click the transition between the previous src of the image and the next src appears for the user and i just dont want such Defoe in the application..

So all what i need is to make the src change while moving to the other div of the app without letting the user notice such a thing

....Here are my html,css,javascript

```js
document.getElementById("Golds").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
 window.location.href='#loginpage';
 var x= document.getElementById("GymLogin");
 x.src="goldsgymlogo.png";
 x.style.display = "inline";
});
document.getElementById("Titans").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
 window.location.href='#loginpage';
 var x= document.getElementById("GymLogin");
 x.src="Titans.jpg";
 x.style.display = "inline";
});
document.getElementById("Smart").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
 window.location.href='#loginpage';
 var x= document.getElementById("GymLogin");
 x.src="smart.png";
 x.style.display = "inline";
});
document.getElementById("SamiaAllouba").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
 window.location.href='#loginpage';
 var x= document.getElementById("GymLogin");
 x.src="Samia-Allouba.jpg";
 x.style.display = "inline";
});
document.getElementById("Fibers").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
 window.location.href='#loginpage';
 var x= document.getElementById("GymLogin");
 x.src="fibers.jpg";
 x.style.display = "inline";
});
```

```css
/*
Thats My CSS
*/

#GymLogin{
 display: none;
 margin-left:30%;
 margin-top:15%;
 max-width:135px;
 max-height:135px;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML CODE HERE-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone Gap trial</title>
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
<link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/font-awesome.min.css' />
 <link rel= 'stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="childbrowser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Torch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="start" class="ourteam text-center">
 <!--start container-->
 <div  class="team">
 <section class="header">
  <div>
  <h1>Train & Game</h1>
  </div>
  </section>
  <div class="container">
  
   <div class="row">

   <div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="Golds" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\goldsgymlogo.png"/>
   <h6>Gold's Gym</h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="Titans" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\Titans.jpg"/>
   <h6>Titans Gym</h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-4">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="Smart" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\smart.png"/>
   <h6>Smart Gym</h6>
   </div>
   </div>

   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row">
   
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="SamiaAllouba" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\Samia-Allouba.jpg"/>
   <h6>Samia Allouba</h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="person">
   <img id="Fibers" class="teamphotos img-circle" src="img\fibers.jpg"/>
   <h6>Fibers Gym</h6>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   </div>

   </div>
   <!--end container-->
 </div> 
 <!--end team-->
 </div>
<!--Our team div end-->



<!-- Start Login Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="loginpage" onblur="deletesrc()">
  <img id="GymLogin" class="img-circle" src=""/>
      <input type="text" size="15"  id="Usernameinput" placeholder="Username">
        <span id="asterisk1" class="asterisk">  </span>  
      <input type="password" id="Passwordinput" placeholder="Password">
      <span id="asterisk2" class="asterisk">  </span>  
  <button class="btn btn-danger" id="GymName">Omar</button>
</div>
<!-- End Login Page -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there's much better ways to do what you're trying to do, you can try this it might help

Instead of changing the ".src" of the images, just have multiple images loaded and hidden, and change the the display of the one you want.

So your HTML becoms

```
<img id="golds" class="GymLogin img-circle" src="golds..."/>
<img class="GymLogin img-circle" src="titans..."/>
<img class="GymLogin img-circle" src="samia..."/>
<img class="GymLogin img-circle" src="fibers..."/>
```

Your css

```
.GymLogin{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Your javascript

```
document.getElementById("Golds").addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
    $('.GymLogin').hide();
    $('#golds').show();
});
```

Haven't tried it but you get the idea.

Comment: Well thanks a lot it worked but there is a little problem,, since you made me load the images 5 times so the login div is now bigger and there is a little transition in the div to the bottom and it affected my page but the image buffering or loading worked fine ,,, so any idea whats that problem for or how it can be solved !? @MegaAppBear

Comment: Can you share your full css?

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply but it's done thank you so much i found a way !! :)